# How can I hide a DIV once it has been shown, without using cookies but with localStorage infos

Tags: jquery, html, css, cookies, local-storage

I have the following question. Being a total beginner in JS I am trying to show a splash page only 1 time to the users - even when the has deactivated his cookies in the broswerd. I did read about localStorage but I could not manage using it properly to make it work. Whenever I deactivated the cookies the splash page did show up, even though I had visited it before.

So far I managed to hide the splash page when the user had NOT deactivated his cookies.

What would I have to add, so that the local Storage is also checked like in this fiddles code:

```
var banner = document.getElementById('banner');
if (localStorage.getItem('set') === 'set') {
  banner.style.display = 'none';
} else {
localStorage.setItem('set', 'set');
}
```

See fiddle here:  jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ogghtw9L/

This fiddle works with a similar technique: jsfiddle.net/Y2D67/

And here is my actual version of the Splash Page:

HTML Code:

```js
/* Add Cookie to check if the splash page has been visited  */
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($.cookie('noShowSplash')) $('#splash').hide();
    else {
        $("#close-splash").click(function() {
            $("#splash").fadeOut(1000);
            $.cookie('noShowSplash', true);    
        });
    }
});
```

```css
#splash {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.81);
    height: 94.5vh;
    padding: 2vh;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:99;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto', Arial;
}
#splash-inner {
   display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    background: green;
    border-radius: 21px;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Here is the normal content</h1>
    <p>Lorakis ipserius dolorandiumnerius</p>
</div>
<div id="splash">
    <div id="splash-inner">
        <h1>Hello..!<br> Welcome to ABC
        <br>
        </h1>
        <h2>We wish you a Great Day..!</h2>
        <br>

        <a id="close-splash" href="#">Continue to the website...</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the Test page on my server right here:
http://werbederbe.de/splash1.html

Thank you in advance,
Atilla

Answer (score 0):

change your code to

```
var banner = document.getElementById('banner');
if (localStorage.getItem('set') != 'set') {
   banner.style.display = 'none';
} else {
  localStorage.setItem('set', 'set');
}
```

Comment: Hello Cristian, thank you for giving a hint - but I really don`t know at all how to "try" that line. It`s like my first night jQuering today.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: `var banner = document.getElementById('splash');
if (localStorage.getItem('set') != 'set') {
   banner.style.display = 'none';
} else {
  localStorage.setItem('set', 'set');
}`

Comment: Since I have no ID called banner i tried with splash. Soon as I switch of the cookies in my broswer I see the splashpage again. Nothing changed so far.

Comment: ` var banner = document.getElementById('splash');
if (localStorage.getItem('set') != 'set') {
   splash.style.display = 'none';
} else {
  localStorage.setItem('set', 'set');
}  `   tried like this, now too

Comment: Its all in the fiddle here: https://codepen.io/great2gether/pen/jwLbev                         I have the same content in a HTML file and also included into wordpress. In both versions the splash div disapperas after clicking the link and wont come back after refreshing the page. For some reason at codepen the splash pages does not care about the Cookie rule and keeps showing the splash page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($.cookie('noShowSplash')) $('#splash').hide();
    else {
        $("#close-splash").click(function() {
            $("#splash").fadeOut(1000);
            $.cookie('noShowSplash', true);    
        });
    }

    $("#close-splash").click(function() {
      $("#splash").fadeOut(1000);
      localStorage.setItem('set', 'set');    
    });
});

var banner = document.getElementById('splash');
console.log(localStorage.getItem('set'));
if (localStorage.getItem('set') === 'set') {
  banner.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you!

For me it still does not work. The thing is I have made an HTML file of that fiddle with the example code I have first posted. You can see it here: http://werbederbe.de/splash-light-version.html - and when I deactivate my cookies The little green box keeps showing up. In the fiddle you can not test it, because soon as you switch off cookies the fiddle code does not show up at all.

So is it, that the code over there does not function, too? Or is it me, just not understanding the concept of those lines of code? Or am I doing something wrong with the JS libraries maybe?

Comment: Additionally I have uploaded a modified version with the code you posted over here: http://werbederbe.de/splash-modified.html and here we have the original version as HTML file: http://werbederbe.de/splash1.html